# How to simulate a 30 inch FR-4 lossy channel (20dB loss) using ltline symbol in LtSpice?

Tags: ltspice, transmission-line, schematic

For designing a high speed serdes system, I need to model a lossy channel of FR-4 substrate of length as 30 inch and 20dB attenuation. How can I implement it in LtSpice tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the lossy transmission line element:

[image]

You'll need more parameters then the ones you mention, such as resistance and capactance and length. Use saturn PCB tool for PCB calcs.

```
.model O1 LRTA(len=10 R=10m L=700n C=3p)
```

More info here:
https://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceHelp.chm/html/O-device.htm

Comment: Can you add a link to the tool you mention?

Comment: https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/

Comment: How to calculate the resistance and other parameters values according to the loss described? Which option in the saturn PCB tool should I choose?